# Get values for the given key from multiple records in javascript ES5

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as follows in the response.

```
Arr = [
{id:1 val:5},{id:2 val:51}
]
```

I need to get the value when id = 2. Is there any straight forward method in js? How can I do it in javascript es5?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is invalid syntax.

Comment: `return Arr.find(item => item.id === 2).value`

Comment: arrow functions are not available in ES5. So can I know a way to do it ES5?

Answer (score 1):

```
const entry = Arr.find(x => x.id === 2);
if (entry) {
   console.log(entry.val);
}
```

Comment: arrow functions are not available in ES5. So can I know a way to do it in ES5?

Comment: replace x => x.id === 2 with function(x) { return x.id ===2; }

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, val: 5 }, { id: 2, val: 51 }];

//ES6
console.log(arr.reduce((p,c) => (c.id == 2 && p.push(c.val), p), []))

//ES5
console.log(arr.reduce(function(p, c) {return (c.id == 2 && p.push(c.val), p)}, []))
```

Comment: arrow functions are not available in ES5. So can I know a way to do it in ES5?

Comment: console.log(arr.reduce(function(p, c) {return (c.id == 2 && p.push(c.val), p)}, []))

Comment: Is there a way to remove [] as well from the output.

Comment: output was [51]. Better if I can get 51 directly @Ziv Ben

Comment: Why are you doing essentially a `.filter().map()`? What you only need is to get the correct item and the value from it.

Comment: If you are sure your `Arr` has only one object with id  = 2, then: arr.reduce(function(p, c) {return (c.id == 2 && p.push(c.val), p)}, [])[0]

Comment: Or: arr.reduce(function(p, c) {return (c.id == 2 && (p = c.val), p)})

Comment: in a second thought, if you have only one object id = 2 i would use: arr.find(function(x) { return x.id == 2 }).val;

Answer (score 0):

you can get value like this:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
  if (Arr[i].id === 2) {
    console.log(Arr[i].val);
  }
}
```

Comment: I need a method in js without looping

Comment: @M.Cooper there is no way to do it without looping. Every method will go through the array in one form or another.